# How to remove iteration involving multiple dataframe filtering?

Tags: python, pandas

```py
    def calculate_user_embeddings(self):
        embeddings: dict = {}

        user_ids = self.ratings["user_id"].unique()
        for id in user_ids:
            print(id)
            embeddings[id] = {}
            this_users_ratings = np.array(self.ratings[self.ratings["user_id"] == id])
            for rating in this_users_ratings:
                this_shows_genres = list(self.shows.loc[self.shows["anime_id"] == rating[1]]["genre"])[0].replace(" ", "").split(",")
                for genre in this_shows_genres:
                    if genre not in embeddings[id]:
                        embeddings[id][genre] = rating[2]
                    else:
                        embeddings[id][genre] += rating[2]
                   
        return embeddings
```

I have this function that needs to look at every row in a pandas DataFrame and then do some other processing based on it's value. Is there any way to avoid all this iteration?

[Shows DF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b1gcO.png)

[Ratings DF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uy60x.png)

definitions for dataframes:

```py
anime_df = pd.DataFrame(anime, columns=[
                        'anime_id', 'name', 'genre', 'type', 'episodes', 'rating', 'members', 'updatedAt', 'createdAt', 'synopsis', 'titleImage'])

ratings_df = pd.DataFrame(
    ratings, columns=['user_id', 'anime_id', 'rating', 'createdAt', 'updatedAt'])
```

Comment: It would be much more likely for your problem to be solved quickly if you would provide a sample of your dataframe.

Comment: Please provide a sample of your dataframe(s). Even just a few rows. I can't help out here otherwise.

Comment: Sorry about that. I've added some images and definitions.

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't see your dataframes it is very hard to tell, but if I were you I would try to concatenate those two dataframes with the options `join="outer"` and `axis=1` (for columns). This way I believe that you can do your query operations at the same time, without using the loops.